# How to handle this view in EntityFramework to set flag in underlying table?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core

I have a "People" table that contains information about people.
I have two kinds of people, users and vendors.
I'm picturing two views, "Users" and "Vendors".
In the underlying table, users do not have the "VendorFlag" set, Vendors do.

I'm picturing the "VendorModel" setting the flag when adding a new vendor.
But I don't know how to do that since it would be looking at the "Vendor" view, not the "People" table.

Another approach would be that the models only know about the views and nothing about the table or the flag and have an insert/update trigger on the views that would update the People table with the correct value for the flag.

But now, I'm really curious how to do this in EF.core.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to edit the Person through the Vendor view if that Person row is not already included in that view. You may need to either directly assess the Person table, define another view to provide a wrapper specifically to Person, or write a stored procedure to set the Vendor flag. Also as part of your design, consider if a User may also be a Vendor and thus may have a need to support Person records that are both.

Comment: Do you expose the VendorFlag in the Vendors view? If so then EF should be able to insert rows with the flag set. If not, have you considered an instead-of insert trigger in which you could set the VendorFlag on the SQL side?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Exposing the flag is an obvious solution that I hadn't considered. I don't see any reason that wouldn't work. Can you post that as a solution so I can accept it? I was assuming that the solution would be more convoluted using EF black magic that I didn't know. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯  .  .  .  .   And yes, a trigger was my alternate solution.

Comment: @TN "no way to edit the Person through the Vendor view,"  yeah, that's where I was stuck.